# Doubt on range-space of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have  a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$. I believe that if T is onto, then, range space of T is equal to W. My reasoning is that if T is onto, then every member of W has a pre-image. So, W should be range space of T. Am I correct or is there something wrong?

Comment: Sure, of course. If the  $T$ is onto then its range is all of $W$

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!